# php soap - SoapFault looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, web-services, soap

im a beginner to programming and following a tutorial on web services with php and soap using Apache2.4 web server.
the tutorial uses soap without wsdl file

Client:

```
<?php
$options = array(
    "location" => "http://localhost/web-services/soap_service.php",
    "uri" => "http://localhost", 
    "trace" => 1,
);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
    $students = $client->getStudentNames();
    echo $students;
} catch(SoapFault $ex) {
    echo var_dump($ex);
}
?>
```

Server:

```
<?php
require_once('Students.php');

$options = array("uri" => "http://localhost");
$server = new SoapServer(null, $options);
$server->setClass('Students');
$server->handle();
?>
```

Class used in server:

```
<?php
class Students{

    public function getStudentFirstName(){

        $studentFN = array("Dale", "Harry", "Shelly", "Bobby",
                "Donna", "Audrey", "James", "Lucy", "Tommy",
                "Andy", "John");

        return $studentFN;

    }

    public function getStudentLastName(){

        $studentLN = array("Cooper", "Truman", "Johnson", "Briggs",
            "Hayward", "Horne", "Hurley", "Moran", "Hill",
            "Brennan", "Smith");

        return $studentLN;

    }

    public function getStudentNames(){

        $studentNames = "Dale Cooper, Harry Truman, Shelly Johnson, " .
                "Bobby Briggs, Donna Hayward, Audrey Horne, " .
                "James Hurley, Lucy Moran, Tommy Hill, " .
                "Andy Brennan, John Smith";

        return $studentNames;

    }

}
?>
```

i keep getting this error:

```
object(SoapFault)#2 (10) { ["message":protected]=> string(33) "looks like we got no XML document"....................
```

so far i did the following:

1. extension=php_soap.dll in php.ini is uncommented (removed ;)
2. php_soap.dll is found in php\ext
3. all files are encoded in UTF-8 without BOM
4. no trailing white spaces after or before the php marks (as far as i can tell)

the tutorial doesnt use a wsdl file, maybe i need to change more settings in php.ini?

what could be the problem???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since uncommenting the `extension=php_soap.dll` line?

Comment: @ND88 Hello, i am getting exactly same what you get, try with so many possibilities, can you pls help me to get out this issue, my code : https://justpaste.it/5qdr6 my output : https://snag.gy/HzRlEv.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED

in soap_client.php, in catch, i added "echo $client->__getLastResponse();"
which gave me the following output:

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
Dale Cooper, Harry Truman, Shelly Johnson, Bobby Briggs, Donna Hayward, Audrey Horne, James Hurley, Lucy Moran, Tommy Hill, Andy Brennan, John Smith
```

that last line is the string i passed to the client.

so what i tried was to **uncomment "always_populate_raw_post_data = -1" in php.ini** as the error suggested & restarted my Apache2.4 web-server
and now it works, getting my string with no errors:

```
Dale Cooper, Harry Truman, Shelly Johnson, Bobby Briggs, Donna Hayward, Audrey Horne, James Hurley, Lucy Moran, Tommy Hill, Andy Brennan, John Smith
```

hope i helped someone with this, as i saw alot of unanswered questions about this error.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Works fine  :) . I searching from 8 AM until now (4:43 PM) Finally found the answer here. Thanks a lot

Comment: ```$client->__getLastResponse()``` was VERY useful for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue in my wamp server. I set the `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` in php.ini file (by removing the `;` ) and then restart the server. It solved this issue for me.